# VoiceOver : can I adapt different voices tones in swift?

Tags: swift, accessibility, voiceover

I'm making a french app in accessibility and I'd like to use some english terms using VoiceOVer.

For that purpose, I decided to use the `accessibilityAttributedLabel` introduced in iOS 11 with `[UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeLanguage:"en"]` only for english terms.

My problem is that french and english voices tones are quite different and that doesn't sound very well.

Does anyone know if it's possible to adjust the voices tones programmatically in this case ?

FYI, I found a workaround by translating all the sentence in phonetics using the `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeIPANotation` key.

Comment: The voice that's chosen is a personal preference. The user can download a variety of voices, male and female, for just about any language and set which voice is their default for a particular language (via settings > accessibility > voiceover > speech). With all due respect, whether **you**, personally, like the voice is irrelevant. Some users hear better with more bass in the voice. Others might require more treble. As long as your app sets the right language, the user will get the voice that **they** want. But thank you for considering this issue and setting the language properly.

Comment: @slugolicious : if it was only a personal unpleasant sound, I would have been adapted.
However, the problem is that the feature suggested by the OS doesn't seem to adapt the voice of the attribute language to this of the user settings.
My question just deals with the way to accomodate this incoming voice to the one that the user wants... definitely not to impose my preference.  ;o)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I didn’t understand the question. I thought you were setting the language property but you didn’t like the voice of the language. Your recent comment sounds like your language setting is not being honored. Is that correct?

Comment: @slugolicious : my language setting is honored but when I use `accessibilityAttributedLabel` with the `AccessibilitySpeechAttributeLanguage` in another language for specific terms, the sound is different. I don't know why the system doesn't adapt this sound with the one defined in the settings. I was looking for a possible solution with code...

Comment: So, to clarify, is this a question about how to implement ["Language of Parts"](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/meaning-other-lang-id.html) in iOS+Swift? Or is that already working, and you just don't like an abrupt change in voice, because it sounds like two different people? It's alright to hear the two languages in two separate voices. That's just how screen readers work, and users are likely to be familiar with this.

Comment: Let's put it another way - it you're trying to have it sound like a Frenchman who speaks English very well, give up.

Comment: Also, in the case where a phrase originated from English, but has been adopted in everyday French, then it may not require a special language attribute at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can change the voice tones, sorry